# Cassandra: range select with incorrect result

Tags: cassandra

I have an issue with range select in cassandra: it some time doesn't returns all data.
It is a 2.1.0 cluster. Binaries available from Apache.

This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE metrics.main_cnt (
gran ascii,
ctx ascii,
io ascii,
eid uuid,
dt bigint,
apdex_s counter,
apdex_t counter,
"count" counter,
error counter,
time counter,
PRIMARY KEY ((gran, ctx, io, eid), dt))
```

I have many rows in that table and if I execute this query:

```
SELECT * from main_cnt WHERE gran = 'min' AND ctx ='A' AND io = 'i' AND eid =4379eec6-ba09-4f70-8862-1c864595c371 and dt in (1420644000000, 1420640400000);
```

I get that result :

```
 gran | ctx | io | eid                                  | dt            | apdex_s | apdex_t | count | error | time
------+-----+----+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------
  min |   A |  i | 4379eec6-ba09-4f70-8862-1c864595c371 | 1420640400000 |     671 |       4 |   677 |     0 | 168253
  min |   A |  i | 4379eec6-ba09-4f70-8862-1c864595c371 | 1420644000000 |     554 |      10 |   566 |     0 | 192666
```

But if i use the a range select like this:

```
SELECT * from main_cnt WHERE gran = 'min' AND ctx ='A' AND io = 'i' AND eid =4379eec6-ba09-4f70-8862-1c864595c371 and dt >= 1420640400000 and dt <= 1420644000000;
```

I only get one row:

```
 gran | ctx | io | eid                                  | dt            | apdex_s | apdex_t | count | error | time
------+-----+----+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------
  min |   A |  i | 4379eec6-ba09-4f70-8862-1c864595c371 | 1420640400000 |     671 |       4 |   677 |     0 | 168253
```

I also tried to increase the range but without better result.
It is not the only case but if i change the dt parameter, i sometime get correct result with several rows.

A *nodetool repair* doesn't fix the problem.

I didn't find any ticket in Jira about such issue.
Does anyone knows about this issue ?
Thanks for any help.

Edit: more informations:
replication factor = 3
cluster has 8 or 9 nodes most of the time
increments are done with java driver 2.1.5 and prepared statements with this command: `UPDATE main_cnt SET time = time + ?, \"count\" = \"count\" + ?, error = error + ?, apdex_s = apdex_s + ?, apdex_t = apdex_t + ? WHERE gran = ? AND dt = ? AND ctx = ? AND eid = ? AND io = ?`

Trace for the normal select:
[trace1.log](https://www.nudge-apm.com/trace1.log)
Trace for the incorrect range select:
[trace2.log](https://www.nudge-apm.com/trace2.log)

Comment: Can you post your IN/UPSERT statements?  When I recreate your table and INSERT the same values above, your range query works for me (2 rows).  So the next logical thing to do, is to make sure that I am inserting data in the same way that you are.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @BryceAtNetwork23.
Data in this table are inserted by batch jobs that increment counters several thousand times per second.
I will try to find the exact increment command that were launched for these exact keys.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a replication factor of 3 and the number of nodes in the cluster is either 8 or 9 most of the time.

Comment: Specifically, I am curious as to how you are generating your `dt` column values.

Comment: Increment are done with Java driver (2.1.5). With this prepared statement:
`private final static String incrMainCql = "UPDATE main_cnt SET time = time + ?, \"count\" = \"count\" + ?, error = error + ?, apdex_s = apdex_s + ?, apdex_t = apdex_t + ? WHERE gran = ? AND dt = ? AND ctx = ? AND eid = ? AND io = ?";`

The `dt` column is bounded as long value.

Comment: Did you delete any records effected by the query? Can you provide traces for both queries? http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html

Comment: I added the traces to my original message. Executed with consistency all.

Comment: Just to make sure, but you're not deleting anything in the table, are you? Trace shows that tombstones are taken into account while executing the range query. But I'm not familiar enough with counters to draw any conclusions based on that fact.

Comment: @StefanPodkowinski actually, there shouldn't be any delete. But this issue has a front-end impact and I first thought the job incrementing those counters was responsible of that issue. So I first decided to delete those information and to launch the jobs that inserted one more time those data (just on a specific range of `dt`). It is only at this moment that I realized that the range select don't return the result it should.So yes there have been deletion on this table but the problem was already there before.

Comment: I will test upgrade to 2.1.6 next week to be sure that 2.1.0 is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why but the issue is fixed after upgrading the cluster to cassandra 2.1.8.